# Statistics problem 8

Tags: statistics

[image]

The way i started this is we know that $$\int_0^1 c(1-y)\,\mathrm{d}y=1$$

Do i just compute this to find c.

Thanks.

Comment: You still have f(y). You can omit it, because $f(y)=c(1-y)$ if $0<y<1$

Comment: You're right i fixed that.Am i going about this question right, or am i way off ?

Comment: I changed my comment.

Comment: Alright removed f(y).

Comment: So is this the right way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\int_0^1 c(1-y)\,\mathrm{d}y=1$$

The constant can be factored out.

$$c\cdot \int_0^1 (1-y)\,\mathrm{d}y=1$$

And $$\int (1-y)\,\mathrm{d}y=y-\frac12 y^2$$

Now insert the limits.

Comment: Oh ok thanks so much.

Comment: You´re welcome.